# How layers Talk to each other in NLayered DDD (Domain Driven Design)

Tags: domain-driven-design

We are trying to adapt DDD for our new project.
we are using Microsoft DDD Nlayer as sample project.
This is more of the DDD question rather than Microsoft Nlayer DDD.
I know  in DDD you are suppose to call the Data layer only form the Application layer and not form Domain layer.  But in the documentation it also says you can still call the data layer from the domain layer (Still it says avoid it). How can I do that? When I try to add reference of Data layer form the Domain layer in visual studio it says ‘Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular depend. 
I know we can get the data in the application layer and then pass it to the domain layer but that’s not going to be always the case I need to get the data based on logic.
What logic can I have in the Domain layer if I don’t have access to data? Most of the time logic will be based on another class and its data (Within same domain or different domain).
Please guide me. This is my ignorance of not knowing how the layers should talk to each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how software (OLTP kind at least) works. Think of a use case, think of the objects involved. Query all the data beforehand. Instantiate the objects using the data. Let the objects collaborate to perform the use case. Save the changed object's data.

An example below:

```
public class IncludePhotoInPortfolioHandler {
  public void Handle(IncludePhotoInPortfolio useCase) {
    var photo = _photoRepo.GetById(useCase.PhotoId);
    var portfolio = _portfolioRepo.GetById(useCase.PortfolioId);
    portfolio.Include(photo);
  }
}
```

If you're changing too many objects at once, you're doing it wrong. You'll run into all sorts of nasty problems. In the odd case you need to fetch data/objects based on identifiers that reside in your objects, expose those identifiers (somehow) and use them to fetch the related objects.

Tip: You might want to read up on DDD in the blue book instead of sticking your head in this NLayered DDD project. Don't put layers on a pedestal.